# How to keep typelibrary instance in stateless call

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-c++

For some very old tool which can call win32 dll only I am making some code in c#. For most of functionality this is completely stateless and this is not a problem at all, but some code need to have couple call.

As per architecture this is :
C++ -> Managed C -> C# type library

in very specific case call need to be something like :
GenerateObjectInstance();

AddRecord(...);
...
AddRecord(...);

ProcessRecords();
FreeInstance();

Parent application doesn't keep instance of created C++ or C# class. How I can make sure this is call to same instance between subsequent call ? This is not a problem to use Mutex and made singleton, my question is actually related to GC. How I can be sure that GC won't remove instance object before next call ?

Thank you in advance,
Dejan

edit :
I am afraid my question wasn't clear enough. I can't keep reference to object.

Old tool can call C method only, this call is stateless. This is C
C method is calling C++/CLI. C++/CLI can't have global variable to managed code (C3145 compilation error)

I've made Singleton for test but that seems GC is removing instance between two call.

Comment: GC can't collect a singleton. In general, it can't collect any object that is still reachable by the program. At the end of the day, any singleton implementation would end up storing an object reference in a global variable; that is sufficient to keep the object alive.

Comment: You'll need a *static* variable in your C++/CLI class.